# python socket stays CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: python, sockets

i have an application which listen on sockets. this application is monitored by nagios. the problem is, that nagios opens sockets and closes those directly.My application sockets stays in CLOSE_WAIT. And i dont understand why this happens. It should run into an error and kill the socket.

```
           while request=="":
                    try:
                            request = self.client.recv ( 1024 ).rstrip()
                    except socket.timeout, msg:
                                    log.error( "no request")
                                    self.client.close()
                                    return
                    except socket.error, msg:
                                    print msg
                                    self.client.close()
                                    return
                    except msg:
                                    log.error(msg)
                                    self.client.close()
                                    return
```

Any ideas how to catch this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CLOSE_WAIT` state means that the socket is expected to be closed by the application.

In the code you posted the socket is only closed on exception. Make sure you close the socket when it receives `EOF`, i.e. check for `not request` before stripping it.

Comment: If the other side closes the stream there is no EOF etc. I dont receive anything! So i cant close on eof...

Comment: @user1010775 If the other side closes the stream there is most definitely an EOS.

Answer (score 1):

When connection is gracefully closed by remote side, the standard BSD `recv` call returns zero. In Python, the returned value is translated to empty string. In both cases it's not considered as an error, so you shouldn't expect any exceptions.

Your code can say:

```
request = self.client.recv(1024).rstrip()
if not request:
  print "Connection closed"
  self.client.close()
```

You can also close the connection in `finally` block after your `try-except` blocks to avoid code duplication. If you expect the server to close the connection after sending the data, you could express it as follow:

```
request = ""
r = True
while r:
  r = self.client.recv(1024)
  request += r
```

Answer (score 1):

are you using the `gevent-websockets` library?

we had this problem too, and did a local patch right before `self.stream = None`, which fixed it for us.

btw calling `close()` on the socket wasn't enough.  from python docs: (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

> Note close() releases the resource associated with a connection but does not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close().

```
$ diff /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geventwebsocket/websocket.py.orig /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geventwebsocket/websocket.py
3c3
< from socket import error
---
> from socket import error, SHUT_RDWR
372a373,379
> 
>             try:
>                 # if we don't close, leaks open files in a CLOSE_WAIT state
>                 self.stream.handler.socket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
>                 self.stream.handler.socket.close()
>             except:
>                 pass
```

note there is a comment in that method:

> Close the websocket and connection, sending the specified code and message.  The underlying socket object is *not* closed, that is the responsibility of the initiator.

so whether this is "right" or not is arguable, but EOD it solved it for us.