# How to force-quit a CLOSE_WAIT socket in Python?

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp

I'm using a pile of `sockets` in my Python script, perhaps 20/s. The are ephemeral, done in three seconds. I've tried to do a good job of sending `socket.close()` to everything, but for some reason `CLOSE_WAIT` statuses on `sockets` still keep piling up.

How can I force-quit these `CLOSE_WAIT` `sockets`? Or can I set a lower `timeout` on them? They end up piling up to the point of crash.

This is my socket code:

```
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.settimeout(2) # 2 seconds timeout

        l_onoff = 1
        l_linger = 0
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', l_onoff, l_linger)) 

        self.s = s          
        streamloop.add_callback(self.connect, s)
```

This is my close:

```
def full_close(self):
    try:
        self.stream.close()
        self.s.close()
    except Exception:
        print 'full_close err: ', sys.exc_info()[1:3]
        pass
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate over all `open` or `close_wait` sockets and then kill them? Like a manual garbage-collection?

Comment: That linger code does nothing except reassert the default setting. Don't do that, it's just an invitation to someone later on to fiddle with it.

Comment: Hey @knutole did you find answer/solution for this?

Comment: @Kazuki Sorry, it's been 7 years, and I don't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are leaking sockets somewhere.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11240739/412080 for more.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah definitively. I'm leaking around 100-200 per 10.000 connections. But I've read that Q, and I can't for the life of me find where they might be leaking. I'm closing everything (twice!). I'm also using `Tornado IOStream` - and do get some warnings here and there, but not enough to account for all the leaked sockets.  Is there a way to gather them all once-in-a-while and just kill them off? Thanks again.